# Angular 2 di container

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, typescript, angular

I m actually studying Angular 2 and I was wondering how does the team do to handle dependency injection in their component ?

**Explanation**

It seems that `Ng2` is based on `ES7` decorator through `typescript`. In fact, class decorator is *launch* (I mean, the code of the decorator) is only interpreted when the class is instanciated.

So, how does the team do to handle component/service injection ?

**Example**

Looking at this code from the documentation :

```
class AComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MyService) aService:MyService) {}
}
```

The injection is made when the constructor of the class is called. This means that MyService has a certain decorator/specific metadata (like `@Injectable`) that allows him to be injected no ?

In this case, it means that there is a registry of services, a list of them accessible through the `@Inject` annotation.

But this means that the framework is able to create and load this repository at **runtime** (this is the important word), which doesn't match with the decorator call (at instanciation for class annotations) ?

Is this mean that every component/services injectable are instanciated at least one time ? Or does it exist something else to inject or execute some decorator at runtime to fill the service registry/container ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: I found this explanation quite useful: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if we should put all of the injectable classes inside one , and only one injector ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In fact, class decorator is "launch" (I mean, the code of the decorator) is only interpreted when the class is instanciated.

The injector yes. But `Component` no, and that is the piece of puzzle you are missing.

```
declare var Component: any;
declare var Inject: any;
declare type MyService = any;
declare var MyService: any;

@Component
class AComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MyService) aService:MyService) {}
}
```

The @Component call will be made at `definition` time. This will allow angular to register the component. The when someone asks for said component the Constructor @Inject will execute and thus angular DI will kick in.

Comment: This di system is really awesome. Do you know how does the injector works in ng2 ?

Comment: `Do you know how does the injector works in ng2` Yes, as an external observer only though :)